# Parse a website, getting all the links and save into mysql database

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

I'm working on PHP and MySQL along with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser. I have to parse a website's pages and fetch some content. For that I put the homepage of website as an initial url and fetched all the anchor tags available on that page.

I have to filter those urls as every link is not useful for me. So, I used regular expression. Required links must be saved into my mysql database.

My questions are:

1. If I extract all the links(around 1,20,000 links) and try to save into mysql DB, I'm getting the following error:
   Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\search-engine\index.php on line 12
2. I can't store data into database.
3. I couldn't filter links.

   ```
   include('mysql_connection.php');
   include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
   $website_name="xyz.html/";

   $html=file_get_html("xyz.html/");
   foreach($html->find('div') as $div)
   {
       foreach($html->find('a') as $a_burrp)
       { 
       echo $a1 = $a_burrp->href . '<br>';
           if(preg_match('/.+?event.+/',$a1, $a_match))
           {
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO scrap_urls(url, website_name, date_added) VALUES(`$a1`, `$website_name`, now())";
           }

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Your "maximum execution time" question has already been asked many times before.

Comment: This is due to the limited knowledge of server information we as a developer have, simpleHTMLDOM parser is easy but quite slow, to its competitors, but because of its scalability and usability for all urls it is widely used. i support @wachme answer PHP is quite slow and needs to be changed

Comment: Hi All, thanx for your help. But everyone solved my first problem only, not second and last prob. I don't know what exactly issue is there in filtering and storing values into db. Plz solve this. I'll be thankful!

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds** because of a config limitation in PHP. You can enlarge this number by adding a line like this at the top of your code:

```
set_time_limit(320);
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

You can also just enlarge the number in your php.ini file in **xampp**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PHP is not the best solution. PHP script is intended to perform quick operations and return response. In your case the script can possibly run for a quite long time. Although you are able to increase [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), I encourage you to use another technology that is much more flexible than standard PHP, such as Python or JavaScript (Node.js)

Answer (score 0):

I also/ usually work with php scripts that need "some time" to finish.

I always run those scripts either as a cronjob or directly from shell or command line using:

php script.php parameters

Though I don't have to mind the execution.
There is a purpose that php_execution_time is usually set to <=60secs.

Regards.